# Browser stuck "loading" a website, and "ping google.com" in terminal hangs

Tags: networking, firefox, internet, ping

Basically, I can't connect to the internet even though I have an ethernet connection active, using my 16.04 LTS on ThinkServer. Started happening a couple days ago.

I can connect to my router 192.168.1.1 and my other devices on the network from FireFox or terminal, but nothing happens if I attempt to access my Plex server, Ombi, or any other program via localhose:port or any other clearnet webstie at all like google.

Even doing "ping google.com" just hangs the process, or entering google.com from Firefox just keeps the new tab in a perpetual "loading" status.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you access sites by address (for instance `ping 8.8.8.8`?)

Comment: Good question, I actually solved it before trying that. For anyone else who runs into the issue, here's what I did: I had attempted to install samba packages for sharing my files on the server on my own network, but without knowing how it contributed to the issue, samba configurations or the package altogether seemed to be what was causing it. So I ran 'sudo apt purge samba'. I also 'sudo nano etc/samba/smb.conf' and commented (aka prefixed the row with a #) the 'server role = standalone server' row